# How can I print the nth (5th) line of every file preceded by the FILENAME using any linux tool?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

So my goal is to extract the fifth line of every file in my directory.
I have a bunch of extension (*.gjf) files in my directory,
and on the fifth line is always "1 0" or "1 1" without the quotes.

So far I know that I can extract those values but not with the filenames attached to them. This is the code I've been using.

```
    awk 'FNR == 5' *.gjf
1  1
0  1
0  1
1  1
1  1
0  1
```

I desire my parsed files to look like this specifically.

```
FILNAME: 1AH7A_TRP-16-A_GLU-9-A.gjf, 1, 1,
FILNAME: 1AH7A_TRP-198-A_ASP-197-A.gjf, 1 , 1,
FILNAME: 1BGFA_TRP-43-A_GLU-44-A.gjf, 0,  1,
FILNAME: CXQA_TRP-61-A_ASP-82-A.gjf, 1, 1,
```

I'd like the filenames to precede these values because I want to run statistics on these files as comma separated value files in R (and I am very capable to do that), and it's very important to me that I can prove that there are only two patterns in my files, the patterns being ordered "0 1" and "1 0".

I even tried listing the files

I tried doing this:

```
grep -l "" *.gjf | awk 'FNR == 5' *.gjf
```

since I knew that I could grep the existence of the files and that would print the list to the screen. But I think I just passed it to awk, and so it computed.

```
1 1
1 1
0 1
1 1 
etc ...
```

I think that it just passed the files to awk and so it printed the nth line. I tried using && instead of |, and it just printed a complete list of the files and then a complete list of the numbers in no organized fashion. Clearly I don't know how to do this.

Comment: can you clarify your expected output... 3 of them have trailing comma and one doesn't...

Comment: Oh, thank you for being so observant. I meant for them all to have trailing commas, so I fixed that.

Comment: no probs :) do mark the answer which solved your issue :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU awk

```
gawk -v OFS=", " 'FNR == 5 {print "FILENAME: " FILENAME, $1, $2; nextfile}' *.gjf
```

Yes, `FILENAME` is the awk variable containing the current filename being processed.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. So the function nextfile in gawk is how you keep the loop going, right?

Comment: yes, it's just a command that skips over the rest of the current file and starts processing the next file. https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nextfile-Statement.html#Nextfile-Statement

Comment: You were right to specify the columns with dollar signs. Thanks to this, I was able to figure out all 208 anomalies in my biophysics computational experiment!

Answer (score 1):

Use this loop:

```
for file in *.gjf; do
  echo "FILENAME: $file, " $(sed 's/ /,/;s/$/,/;5q;d' "$file")
done
```

- `sed '5q;d'` extracts the 5th line

Comment: OMG! It works perfectly. Thank you! I think I understand how the loop works!

Comment: Just modified so that it adds a `,` at the end as well.